# How do I apply BODMAS or BIDMAS to my Java calculator code?

Tags: java, calculator

My code works with 2 sequences such as '2x5=' which would output 10.0. However I need it to work with multiple different sequences with different operators. So if I tried to input '2x5/2=' the output would be 2.5. it clearly only takes the last two sequences, In this case being '5/2'. I've tried so many things to figure this out and I need help.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Calculator implements ActionListener {

JFrame frame;
JTextField textfield;
JButton[] numberButtons = new JButton[10];
JButton[] functionButtons = new JButton[6];
JButton addButton, subButton, mulButton, divButton;
JButton equButton, clrButton;
JPanel panel;

Font myFont = new Font("Ink Free", Font.BOLD, 30);

double num1 = 0, num2 = 0, result = 0;
char operator;

Calculator() {

    frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(420, 550);
    frame.setLayout(null);

    textfield = new JTextField();
    textfield.setBounds(50, 25, 300, 50);
    textfield.setFont(myFont);

    addButton = new JButton("+");
    subButton = new JButton("-");
    mulButton = new JButton("x");
    divButton = new JButton("÷");
    equButton = new JButton("=");
    clrButton = new JButton("AC");

    functionButtons[0] = addButton;
    functionButtons[1] = subButton;
    functionButtons[2] = mulButton;
    functionButtons[3] = divButton;
    functionButtons[4] = equButton;
    functionButtons[5] = clrButton;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        functionButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
        functionButtons[i].setFont(myFont);
        functionButtons[i].setFocusable(false);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        numberButtons[i] = new             

JButton(String.valueOf(i));
        numberButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
        numberButtons[i].setFont(myFont);
        numberButtons[i].setFocusable(false);
    }

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(50, 100, 300, 300);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4, 10, 10));
    // panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    panel.add(numberButtons[7]);
    panel.add(numberButtons[8]);
    panel.add(numberButtons[9]);
    panel.add(divButton);
    panel.add(numberButtons[4]);
    panel.add(numberButtons[5]);
    panel.add(numberButtons[6]);
    panel.add(mulButton);
    panel.add(numberButtons[1]);
    panel.add(numberButtons[2]);
    panel.add(numberButtons[3]);
    panel.add(subButton);
    panel.add(clrButton);
    panel.add(numberButtons[0]);
    panel.add(equButton);
    panel.add(addButton);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.add(textfield);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (e.getSource() == numberButtons[i]) {
                

      textfield.setText(textfield.getText().concat(String.valueOf(I  )));
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == addButton) {
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(textfield.getText());
        operator = '+';
        textfield.setText("");
    }
    if (e.getSource() == subButton) {
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(textfield.getText());
        operator = '-';
        textfield.setText("");
    }
    if (e.getSource() == mulButton) {
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(textfield.getText());
        operator = '*';
        textfield.setText("");
    }
    if (e.getSource() == divButton) {
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(textfield.getText());
        operator = '/';
        textfield.setText("");
    }
    if (e.getSource() == equButton) {
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(textfield.getText());

        switch (operator) {
            case '+':
                result = num1 + num2;
                break;
            case '-':
                result = num1 - num2;
                break;
            case '*':
                result = num1 * num2;
                break;
            case '/':
                result = num1 / num2;
                break;
        }

        textfield.setText(String.valueOf(result));
        num1 = result;
    }
    if (e.getSource() == clrButton) {
        textfield.setText("");
    }
}
```

}

I tried to apply stacks and pops into my actionPerformed part of my code but no matter what I try, it ruins the function of my original code, which is not what I want of course.

Comment: It is not possible to know what is wrong with the code, if you do not post the code

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)